# SkyDrive is now OneDrive

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[OneDrive for Everything in Your Life](http://blog.onedrive.com/onedrive-for-everything-your-life/)

> Today we are pleased to announce that SkyDrive will soon become OneDrive.

We have a good bunch of questions about [skydrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/skydrive). Please re-tag them as [onedrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) and make "skydrive" a synonym.

Comment: Aaaaaannnnd "Database error" on the link you posted. I guess SkyDrive fell out of the air.

Comment: It probably got slashdotted. (Or whatever the equivalent is. I saw the article on Ars Technica, I think.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done.

For a moment I was really confused why the Stack Exchange app is sending me Microsoft spam.

Comment: "Oh, hey, I can help with that. Tags one, two, three questions. Huh. No more questions tagged Skydrive." OLIVERRRRRRRRRRRR.